# Find out IF a process killed the current process

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security

Any way to figure out IF the current process of the program is killed by another other process (I don't need to know which process, only that its killed by any other).

Note: It IS possible, see: http://bugslasher.net/2011/04/17/who-the-hell-killed-my-process/
But this requires a third party application. I'm sure this can be done by myself too (somehow).

//edit: Actually I googled a bit and the application GFlag will create a registry entry and windows itself tells if the monitored program is shut down. Sadly this also means that the current application has to create this registry entry at start BUT when the current application is killed before it starts, it's not logged.

Comment: "this also means that the current application has to create this registry entry at start BUT when the current application is killed before it starts, it's not logged." if you think about it, this will be true for *anything* your own program might attempt to do. If someone can kill it early enough, it won't have started executing *any* instructions. So if that's a genuine concern, you're out of luck.

Comment: "when the current application is killed before it starts" then what'd you expect to do about it? Your app's code has not run. Where/what/how do you imagine your app "detects" it when the app has not ran? You need some third or fourth pair of eyes.